# Why is the delete post button not working correctly in a blog application built on rails using scaffold?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, routes, scaffold

for some reason the delete post button is not deleting but taking you to the article page, the alert message is not even triggered. It's as if the read button were identical to the delete button.

I tried it in 2 ways, the first:

```
<div class="card bg-light">
    <div class="card-body">
        <h4><%= link_to post.title, post %></h4>

        <%= link_to "Read", post, class: 'btn btn-primary' %>   
        <%= link_to "Edit", edit_post_path(post), class: 'btn btn-secondary' %> 
        <%= link_to "Exclude", post, method: :delete, class: 'btn btn-danger', data: {confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete?'} %>
    </div>
</div>
```

The second:

```
<div class="card bg-light">
    <div class="card-body">
        <h4><%= link_to post.title, post %></h4>

        <%= link_to "Read", post, class: 'btn btn-primary' %>   
        <%= link_to "Edit", edit_post_path(post), class: 'btn btn-secondary' %> 
        <%= link_to "Exclude", post_path(post), method: :delete, class: 'btn btn-danger', data: {confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete?'} %>
    </div>
</div>
```

None worked, delete button still failed, can anyone help me?

Detail, I used the scaffold to create the base of the application.

Comment: Take a look at the "Exclude" button in the browser dev tools, you should see a form has been created (by rails-ujs) with a couple of hidden inputs, including one with name attribute '_method' and value attribute 'delete'. If you're not seeing this, you probably don't have rails-ujs on the page. Are you using the asset pipeline? If so, you should see '//= require rails-ujs' in one of the included js files, e.g. application.js.  Or are you using webpacker to compile the javascript?

Comment: Please mentions few more things like what do you see in the logs when you try to delete a record and what is the html output of this Exclude button in the inspect element section ?

Comment: You need to include `rails-ujs` in your application in order to use links with custom HTTP verbs (like `DELETE`). Are you using Webpacker?

Comment: Would you provide some more code? It would be useful to see the controller action, routes and any other related code to this delete intention. Maybe there is some typo somewhere or something is missing elsewhere.